# Can you guess what friend I'm imagining?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

[image: 18th what?]

What character am I thinking of? I just **imagined** that instead of solving puzzles, I could make friends by making my own.

**BONUS:**

> It was today that I figured out what two letters spell a tear.. I.. I forgot. Can you remind me what they were? (This one is for people who already know who the character is)

Comment: You only posted this six hours ago. I would give it at least a full day to allow people in all timezones to see it before doing anything else.

Comment: @PDT I don't think that's true. I would say 1 per day is a maximum (again, to allow people in all timezones a chance to see the update), not a recommendation. There are plenty of users who don't check in to PSE every day, and not everyone is interested in every sort of puzzle. I certainly wouldn't worry if a puzzle didn't get any obvious attention for a few days.

Comment: For the first row... rot13(Gvzrf gnoyr + 10 =, znxrf zr guvax bs Gnoyr + Gra Vf, be va bgure jbeqf Gnoyr Graavf.) Is this on the right track?

Comment: Rot13(Lrnu.. Lbh'er trggvat cerggl pybfr...)

Comment: I apologize if I added too much at once. And, this isn't the best puzzle as this is my first one and I'm new to this website. :D

Comment: As I've told you before, "imagining of" is not a grammatical way to end your title. It's either "thinking of" or "imagining"

Comment: It's on purpose... It's not meant to be gramatical

Comment: But, I guess imagining might work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your imaginary friend is:

> [BING BONG](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Bing_Bong) from the [DISNEY MOVIE INSIDE OUT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Out_(2015_film)).

*I just imagined that instead of solving puzzles, I could make friends by making my own*.

> He was the imaginary friend of Riley Andersen in the movie!

The first rebus on the top

> is **TABLE** (times table)+ **TEN** (the number)**IS** (equals sign) which makes **TABLE TENNIS**. We are then supposed to convert this to its synonym: **PING PONG**…

The second rebus (18th)13.

> is **(r)13** thus replacing the 18th with **r** since it is is the 18th letter of the Modern Latin Alphabet. This hints at the **[rot 13 substitution cipher](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)**.

What to do with the C=O?

> The puzzle then wants us to apply the cipher to both of the letters in C=O as hinted by in the arrow pointing to it and doing so we get P=B.

> And so putting everything together we should change the letter Ps in **PING PONG** into Bs and doing so we get **BING BONG**.

Bonus

> BING BONG is known to cry candies. The two letters are ‘C and Y’ making ‘CandY’.

Comment: YOU ARE SO CLOSE! But, not quite there yet.

Comment: Um... I'm going to update the image to help.

Comment: Done! I hope it makes sense now!

Comment: I understand why you thought all of that though. Next time, I'll try to make a puzzle where there can't be multiple answers. But, that's really hard.

Comment: The character is wrong. Also, the last spoiler and the last part of the third spoiler. But, the rest is right.

Comment: I saw that you change the last one. That doesn't make the answer right. It's not CATBUS

Comment: I'm so confused. What do you think the answer is? It now says KING KONG but you didn't change the rest.

Comment: YAY! You got it!

Comment: Sorry, I could've made this puzzle better.

Comment: You should have had the arrow as your original layout also the hints were completely unhelpful.  Other wise it’s perfectly fine. Also I would recommend just deleting the hints they are extremely confusing and are more likely to mislead than help 

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh.. yeah sorry.

Comment: But, can you figure out the bonus? It's not required but, it's not really that hard.

Comment: Yeah, that's right :D